# How can I the image start from a new line when using dita-ot-3.0 pdf plug outputting PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, dita-ot

hope someone to help me, thanks!
When I use dita-ot-3.0 to output pdf, I find in many places, the images are displayed in the same line with text.
I try two plugins:
- default pdf2 plugin
- a customization pdf plugin using PDF Plugin Generator at https://github.com/jelovirt/dita-generator (I didnot find any place to set image attribute)

So here is my question, I write xml like this:
[source xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aUQ9.png)
When I output pdf, I get this:
[image is shown in the same line with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE0Re.png)

there are many other images showing like that. How can I make the image show starting from a new line? Am I misusing the  element？ Is the difference between inline element or block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting the attribute `placement="break"` to the `<image>` element. This is explained in the [spec](https://www.oxygenxml.com/dita/1.3/specs/langRef/base/image.html).

Comment: Yep, i forget the attribute. Thanks a lot.